# How to set layout width to view the same in different screen sizes

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have a `ListView` to show 3 `TextView` beside each others. The problem is when the screen size is shorter than the row's width. You can see the picture here:
[image: http://upload.tehran98.com/upme/uploads/9b7b38b3e2340ea31.png]

This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/shareRow"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/message_row_style"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_purple"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_purple"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:gravity="right"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtStatus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_purple"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:gravity="right" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I could not see the image and even i could not get your problem clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution:

Set

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

on all your text views.

A much more elegant solution would be to specify different layouts optimized for different screen sizes. Please read this article, especially the section on screen size configuration qualifiers.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Then, create two different layouts, one for large screens where all information is displayed in one row and one layout for normal screens with three rows, each displaying one text view.

Answer (score 1):

```
// try this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/shareRow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/message_row_style"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDescription"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_purple"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDate"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_purple"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:gravity="right"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtStatus"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_purple"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:gravity="right" />
</LinearLayout>
```